# ForEach two arrays - simple solution possible?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling with a simple solution I can't find. I want to build a picker which shows the flags and selects the Language code from the other array. There must be a simple solution. so long I helped myself with this ugly `onChange` crutch.

Any suggestions?

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    
    @AppStorage ("language")var language: String = "de"
    @State private var flag: String = ""
    var languages = ["de", "en", "pl"]
    var languageFlags = ["", " ", "" ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack{
                
                Picker("", selection: $flag) {
                    ForEach(languageFlags, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                            .font(.caption2)       
                    }
                    
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                
            }.onChange(of: flag, perform: { value in
                if flag == "" {language = "de"}
                if flag == " " {language = "en"}
                if flag == "" {language = "pl"}
            })
        }
        
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language))
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow :-) i will try all three solution. all of them are looking leaner than mine. Swiftpunks solutions looks like the solution I couldn't find :-)

Comment: So many answers in so little time. Impressive!

Comment: I would wish myself so many answers in my questions! I believe you will get more answers, LoL

Comment: It‘s awesome. It has to be the right question. My previous question had no answers :-) thank you, guys!

Comment: yes, I think your question is right question and would be needed in every app, because every app need kind of language support for users.

Comment: It‘s so helpful to try to understand other solutions for the same problem. Coding is learning :-)

Comment: Absolutely, learning is by doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would also a good answer for your need, you should define a custom type like I did! With my code, the selected Language saved directly and you should not worry about it! more secure I would say.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LanguageView()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Language: Hashable {
    let language: String
    let flag: String
}
```

---

```
let languageArray: [Language] = [Language(language: "de", flag: ""), Language(language: "en", flag: " "), Language(language: "pl", flag: "")]
```

---

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    @AppStorage ("language")var selectedFlag: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Picker("", selection: $selectedFlag) {
                    ForEach(languageArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(languageArray[index].flag)
                            .font(.caption2)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
            .onAppear() { print("language is: " + languageArray[selectedFlag].language) }
            .onChange(of: selectedFlag) { newValue in
                print("language is: " + languageArray[newValue].language)
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not type-safe but fix the problem.

Comment: Why are you declaring the array as a global variable? Btw Swift naming convention is to name all your vars starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I do not like make my View busy for variables and I defined it outside as let, I think it is better in this way, and about lowercase, you are right I forgot to control it, I fix it, thanks

Comment: @mahan: Once we create our **languageArray** which is a **let** we would access it with index and from the other hand in the fact we would never access it, because Just Picker would access it, so there is no space for mistake that you were worry about type-safe. I think using a **let array** is also safe enough. and when we are accessing we are using like this **languageArray[index].flag** that **flag** or **language** is autocomplete and kind of type-safe. but I know it is not an enum, and also it makes its job well as also,

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enum for `Language`:

```
enum Language: String, CaseIterable {
    case de, en, pl
    
    var flag: String {
        switch self {
        case .de:
            return ""
        case .en:
            return " "
        case .pl:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you don't need extra `@State` variables nor `onChange`:

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    @AppStorage("language") var language: Language = .de

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Picker("", selection: $language) {
                    ForEach(Language.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.flag)
                            .font(.caption2)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language.rawValue))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have Array of type `[(String,String)]` a `Tuple`. If you don’t want parameter names, you can also access them using indices `0` and `1`

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    
    @AppStorage ("language")var language: String = "de"
    @State private var flag: Int = 0
    
    var languageFlags = [(flag:"",language:"de"), (flag:" ",language:"en"), (flag:"",language:"pl")]
    
   
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Picker("", selection: $flag) {
                    ForEach(languageFlags.indices) { (index) in
                        Text(languageFlags[index].flag)
                            .font(.caption2)
                    }
                    
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                
            }.onChange(of: flag, perform: { index in
                language = languageFlags[index].language
            })
        }
        
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **enum** for languages and confirm to the [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) protocol so that you can itereate over all of its cases (languages).

> An enumeration defines a common type for a group of related values and
> enables you to work with those values in a **type-safe** way within your
> code. [https://docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)

```
enum Language: String, CaseIterable {
    case de = ""
    case en = " "
    case pl = ""

    var name: String {
        get { return String(describing: self) }
    }
}



struct LanguageView: View {
    @AppStorage("language") var language: Language = .de

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Picker("", selection: $language) {
                    ForEach(Language.allCases, id: \.self) { language in
                        Text(language.rawValue)
                            .font(.caption2)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language.name))
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a [locale identifier](https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273) to `.environment(\.locale` - something like `de`, `en`, `en_US` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody else posted an answer that preserved your combining the flags for the US and the UK. If you need to map from a user-selected flag to a language, a Dictionary seems like the obvious choice:

```
let flagsAndLanguages = ["": "de", "" : "en", "": "en", "" : "pl"]

let aFlag = ""

func languageForFlag(_ flag: String) -> String {
    return flagsAndLanguages[aFlag] ?? "unknown"
}

print("The lanagugage for the flag \(aFlag) is '\(languageForFlag(aFlag))'")
```

This outputs `The lanagugage for the flag  is 'en'`.

Looking up entries in a Dictionary is extremely fast. `KeyValuePairs`, in contrast, are slower, but preserve ordering. I don't think you need to preserve a specific order of your flags/languages, do you?

Comment: `KeyValuePairs` is slow? It is a `RandomAccessCollection` O(1). I don't think that accessing a dictionary value is faster than accessing an array element. Btw if you only need one flag you should define the dictionary key type as `Character`

Comment: To quote the docs on `KeyValuePairs`: "Use a KeyValuePairs instance when you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t require the fast key lookup that the Dictionary type provides. Unlike key-value pairs in a true dictionary, neither the key nor the value of a KeyValuePairs instance must conform to the Hashable protocol." (The key is not hashed, so I would expect the lookup to be `O(n)`. I haven't benchmarked it, but Apple's docs explicitly says it is not as fast as the key lookup for dictionaries.)

Comment: Good point about making the keys type `Character`. I got lazy.

Comment: This if you don't know the index "fast key lookup"